# How can i merge multiple CSV files using scala?

Tags: scala, merge

I would like to merge these two csv files using scala,
R-1.csv

```
empNo, slotNo
13648,[49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 1-3-5-7]
24824,[52 51 53 50 37 36 38]

R-2.csv

empNo, slotNo
23241,[48 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 1-4-5-7]
09344,[59 51 53 50 37 36 38]
```

I have these two files in scala, can someone please explain how i can merge these two files into one, and also looking for the way to merge these two files and change the order of records, something like this,

```
final csv :
empNo, slotNo
13648,[49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 1-3-5-7]
09344,[59 51 53 50 37 36 38]
24824,[52 51 53 50 37 36 38]
23241,[48 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 1-4-5-7]
```

Comment posted as an answer earlier by @AlwaysLearner, the comment is deleted for some reason, hence adding it here, as i cant paste the code in the comment section as it exceeds the length.

```
import java.io.File
  import com.github.tototoshi.csv._

  object CsvMergeExample extends App {
    // Read CSV files
    val reader1 = CSVReader.open(new File("R-1.csv"))
    val rows1 = reader1.all()
    reader1.close()

    val reader2 = CSVReader.open(new File("R-2.csv"))
    val rows2 = reader2.all()
    reader2.close()

    // Merge the two CSV files
    val mergedRows = rows1 ++ rows2

    // Sort the merged rows by the first column
    val sortedRows = mergedRows.sortBy(row => row.head.toInt)

    // Write the merged CSV to a new file
    val writer = CSVWriter.open(new File("merged.csv"))
    writer.writeAll(sortedRows)
    writer.close()
  }
```

Comment: @AlwaysLearner Can you please repost the comment. I am not sure why it is deleted :(

Comment: Not sure if the comment is deleted, i am not able to see the comment any longer. :( Can you please repost the comment?

Comment: @AlwaysLearner Can you please post the comment as how to merge csv files and remove the headers and keep only the header of the first csv file, and how to shuffle after csv files are merged? sorry for the trouble, not sure why the comment is deleted :(

Comment: I have only half of the code from the comment , and addd it above, can you please update the code further to shuffle the rows and retain only one header of the csv file after merging?